# How do you access an objects properties?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm not being lazy. I am following along with *C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4* and one of the examples in the book diverges from how Qt is working for me.

It has me make a dialog and then hook up some signals and slots. Well that does not work and so I tried some reality checks. I can't even edit the objects properties manually.

**Here is main**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <iostream>
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Ui::GoToCellDialog ui;
    QDialog *d = new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(d);
    d->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**and here is my dialog .cpp file**

```
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

GoToCellDialog::GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GoToCellDialog)
{
    cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"; // i never see this
    ui->setupUi(this); // but if i comment out this it doesnt init
    ui->okButton->setEnabled(true); // this does nothing
}

GoToCellDialog::~GoToCellDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**Here is the GoToCellDialog form in design mode**
[image]

I am just trying to enable okButton, which is disabled by default. Also, if I cout << "abc"; it doesn't show up. Can you please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

You've created a `GoToCellDialog` class and implemented its constructor. But you don't create an object of this class. Of course, your constructor is not being executed. You need to replace `QDialog` to `GoToCellDialog` in your main function.

If you really need `QDialog`, not `QWidget`, you need to derive `GoToCellDialog` class from `QDialog`, not `QWidget`. There is an option for that while you create a designer form class in Qt Creator.

You create a `Ui::GoToCellDialog` in the main function, but another one is created in the `GoToCellDialog` class (note the `ui` private member). If you would instantiate your class, it would give you 2 instanses of `Ui::GoToCellDialog` which shouldn't be done. Remove `Ui::GoToCellDialog` from your main function.

I think you've confused `GoToCellDialog` class defined by you and `Ui::GoToCellDialog` class generated internally. `Ui::GoToCellDialog ui` is private member of `GoToCellDialog`, you don't need to instantiate it anywhere else.

See also: [Calculator Form Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-calculatorform.html).

Comment: i am confused but that helps a little. i may have to skip this section since it's confusing me more.